# Enumerate after \label

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I have the following code:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{thm} \label{mythm}
   \begin{enumerate}
      \item 
   \end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\ref{mythm}
```

The ref prints the right number. However, when I click on it, it will lead me to a wrong page (basically, to the beginning of the document).  pdflatex also has some warning.  If I add $ $ between `\begin{thm}` and `\begin{enumerate}`, the problem disappears, but now, the enumeration starts a new line.  Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `\phantomsection` command from `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\phantomsection \label{mythm}
   \begin{enumerate}
      \item 
   \end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\ref{mythm}

\end{document}
```

Another option would be to use the [ntheorem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) package instead of `amsthm`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\mbox{}\newpage
\begin{thm}
\label{mythm}
   \begin{enumerate}
      \item
   \end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\newpage
\ref{mythm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For ntheorem, do I need to also define the proof environment?

Comment: @brian: if you load the package with the `standard` option, then some predefined theorem-like environments become available, `proof` amongst them (you'll also need the `thmmarks` package option to activate the endmark). If you don't load those options, you'll have to define your own `proof` environment.

Answer (score 6):

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}    
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm} \label{thm:test}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First thing.
\item Second thing.
\item Third thing.
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

Reference to Theorem~\ref{thm:test}.

\end{document}
```

The theorem environment of `amsthm` delays the anchor setting to the start of the next paragraph via `\everypar`. However the first `\item` of environment `enumerate` clears it by `\everypar{}`. Thus the anchor is lost for the `\label{thm:test}`.

A normal paragraph start would set the anchor. The [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187077/16967) of John Kormylo start the paragraph with `\strut`, an invisible rule with a height and depth.
The following example uses `\noindent`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
\noindent\label{thm:test}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First thing.
\item Second thing.
\item Third thing.
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

Reference to Theorem~\ref{thm:test}.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \noindent]

Then the first item moves from the theorem title line to the next line, the number aligned with the other numbers of the enumeration. Therefore I would call it a feature.

Otherwise `\phantomsection` instead of `\noindent` can be used, as shown in the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14003/16967) of Gonzalo Medina:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\def\thmautorefname{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
\phantomsection\label{thm:test}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First thing.
\item Second thing.
\item Third thing.
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

Theorem~\ref{thm:test} and \autoref{thm:test}.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \phantomsection]

`\phantomsection` does not start a new paragraph, therefore the original anchor for the theorem label is still lost. But it creates a new anchor, that is then used by the following `\label`.

However, `\phantomsection` does not create a theorem anchor, but an anchor with the internal name of a section. Therefore `\autoref` will refer to the theorem as "section".

As workaround, the correct anchor can be set via `\hyper@anchor`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\def\thmautorefname{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
\makeatletter
\hyper@anchor{\@currentHref}%
\makeatother
\label{thm:test}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First thing.
\item Second thing.
\item Third thing.
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

Theorem~\ref{thm:test} and \autoref{thm:test}.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \hyper@anchor]

Comment: A better command than `\phantomsection` would be welcome. ;-) What about `\makeanchor`?

Comment: @egreg: Is not this easy. Also a unique anchor name is needed. I doubt, a normal user would know to use `\@currentHref` or `thm.\theHthm` here.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: I don't really understand what you mean. And I know that it's hard to patch packages so that they fit with hyperref, but what about doing so for amsthm?

Comment: @AntoineChambert-Loir I do not know, what are you referring to, but if you want to improve the compatibility of `amsthm` and `hyperref`, then you or other volunteers are free to go ahead.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Inded, I'll try to find out how to arrange that. As a matter of fact, my question was referring to your comment "I doubt, a normal user..."

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek -- when i try your last example, i still get item (1) starting on a new line.  this may be the result of different versions of *something* (still using tex live 2012), but i'm not sure what.  can you please send me, off-line, a list of the file versions that result in the run-in list.  thanks.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, done via mail. The example was compiled with `pdflatex`. With a different driver, `latex/dvips/ps2pdf`, then the first item also moves to the new line.

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler...

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{mythm}\strut% ******************
   \begin{enumerate}
      \item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\ref{mythm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I suspect that this clever solution may be more *clever* and less a *solution* to the problem at hand. In particular, I suspect that it might break down if and when either `amsthm` or `hyperref` are updated at some point in the future. However, this is no more than a suspicion for just now. I'd be happy to be shown wrong.

Comment: @Mico - One would hope than any updates will actually fix the problem in the first place.

Comment: One *should* always hope... Nothing wrong with hope! :-)

Comment: BTW, \leavevmode also works and is probably the simplest solution of all.