# reference link in pdf file is not working correctly (problem with enumerate?)

Tags: hyperref, enumerate, amsthm

In the following example a bug appears which I cannot explain.
in the pdf-output, the link to Theorem 1 does not work correctly, clicking it jumps to the beginning of the document BLABLA. The printed reference is correct, just the link is broken.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

BLABLA
\newpage

\begin{Thm}\label{label1}       % a theorem
\begin{enumerate}
\item item1
\end{enumerate}
\end{Thm}

blublblbu reference~\ref{label1}        %references the theorem
\end{document}
```

Somehow it seems to be related with `enumerate`, since the problem vanishes when I replace

```
 \begin{enumerate}
   \item item1
  \end{enumerate}
```

by just some text

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I believe this is the same problem as in [enumerate after label](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14000/). Does the answer to the linked question help you?

Comment: Interesting!  The aux file shows no difference.  Placing a \hypertarget around the enumerate works.  If you add any text between the Thm and the enumerate cause the ref to work again.

Comment: Best I can figure, enumerate is resetting the target before label has a chance to use it, and without a target a PDF goto goes to the top of the first page.  Note, a label inside the enumerate will link to the item, not the theorem.

Comment: The PDF looks fine (as far as I can tell).

Comment: @user49605: I have just checked: It is definitely the same problem as described in the link provided by egreg: Use the `\phantomsection` just before `\label{label1}`

Comment: yes, this is indeed a duplicate and the answer in the other thread fixed my problem. sorry for that