# itemize environment inside theorem

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, theorems, itemize

When I have an itemize environment inside a theorem and refer to the theorem later on, the document doesn't point to the right location. For example, consider the following toy example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11 pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs,amsfonts} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\title{Test}
\maketitle

\newpage

\section{Test}
\begin{thm}\label{Thm}
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\item b
\end{itemize}
\end{thm}

\newpage

Theorem \ref{Thm} is a test.


\end{document}
```

When I click the referring number of the Theorem, the document jumps to the first page, instead of the desired second page. Could anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related/almost duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14000/enumerate-after-label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a manual hyperlink mark using `\phantomsection`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\title{A title}\author{An author}
\maketitle

\newpage

\section{A section}

\begin{thm}\phantomsection\label{Thm}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item a
    \item b
  \end{itemize}
\end{thm}

Theorem \ref{Thm} is a test.

\end{document}
```

The problem here seems to stem from a combined page-break + sectional unit + list environment, where no proper mark is set. That is, TeX is still be in vertical mode. An appropriate issue of `\leavevmode` would also work, but that may alter the placement of content.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Werner! This helps a lot!