# Avoid the spurious space \noindent adds at the beginning of a theorem

Tags: spacing, hyperref

This question is related to [Enumerate after \label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14000/18401) and [Heiko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193105/18401) (with `\noindent` trick). As pointed out by Heiko:

> Then the first item moves from the theorem title line to the next line, the number aligned with the other numbers of the enumeration. Therefore I would call it a feature.

and I fully agree.

But, as pointed out by the following MWE, this trick also adds a spurious space if the theorem starts with a line of text (and not by e.g. a list): this is a problem if one wants to automatically avoid the trouble encountered in the referenced question by inserting this extra `\noindent` at the definition level:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\thmcontent}{%
  \multido{\n=0+1}{15}{%
    \multido{\n=0+1}{10}{\n }%
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
  \label{thm}
  \thmcontent
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
  \noindent\label{newthm}
  \thmcontent
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're disabling the mechanism whereby the `\label` command is issued in vertical mode, so the space generated by the end-of-line is ignored. Add `%` after `\label{newthm}`. In Heiko's answer the space is invisible, due to `enumerate` starting immediately thereafter.

Comment: you should almost never use `\noindent` in latex

Comment: Note that `\noindent` does not add a space, the space is added by the white space in your source file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Usually I don't use `\noindent` but I see a lot of people using it. Is there a pointer that explains why this is not recommended?

Comment: Because 99 times out of 100 if you do use it you get the issue noted in this question:-) Also from the logical markup point of view it should be a style issue, you should not go `\section{foo} \noindent`... the choice of when to indent after sections (or other things) should be a document-level setting not forced by markup in each section.

Comment: @egreg [New edition of a previous, removed, comment] Sigh... I should have understand this myself. Nevertheless, therefore `\noindent` is definitively **not** a way to go in order to automatically avoid the trouble at the definition level: it would require for the user to add a `%` after the `\label{...}` of each labeled theorem, which is quite unusual. Too bad a solution with something that doesn't leave the vertical mode doesn't exist.