# Why does the non-pdf latex engine behave differently from pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, e-tex

In the question
[Enumerate after \label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193105/579)
an admirable answer addresses the problem of how to label and link
the theorem number when the theorem begins with an enumerated
list, and while doing so, how to start the list on the same
line as the theorem header.

The answer (by Heiko Oberdiek) involves placing a unique hyper-anchor
between the theorem header and the start of the list.

Unfortunately, this works only with direct pdf output, not when
the job is compiled to `dvi` and then converted to `ps/pdf`.
In the `.dvi` output, the beginning of the list is invariably
shifted to the next line.

The question here is, what is different between the two TeX
engines that prevents the `.dvi` output from being the same
as the `.pdf` output?  And is there a package that remedies
this lapse?

**Rationale**

We need to fix the problem that `dvips` adds an extra line when
theorems begin with `enumerate`, because the the AMS production
stream requires the `dvi` route for output destined for print,
so the use of `pdftex` or `xetex` is not an option.  And, since
the linked output for on-line posting is created using `pdflatex`,
the paging of the two different outputs would be different, which
is not an option either.

The question is often asked, Why does AMS production depend on
`dvips`?

The reason for the `dvi` requirement mainly involves the need to
evaluate the quality of graphics before publication (this is also
the reason that AMS requests `.eps` files).  The goal is for
graphics to accurately convey the intended information on the
printed page as well as in electronic form; the requirements of
offset printing are quite different from what looks good on screen.

Automated checking of features like line width, color differentiation
(including the ability to distinguish color density and contrast,
and the effects of grayscaling) and size of type in context is
relatively simple when a graphic file is in PostScript form, even
when scaling is applied via `\includegraphics`, but nearly impossible
once the graphic is embedded in a final `.pdf` file, when (as a
colleague has described it) everything has been turned into hamburger.
GUI tools do exist for examining pdf graphics, but these require
evaluation of each graphic individually, and increase the time
required for checking; this, in turn, increases both the cost of
production, and the elapsed time until proof can be returned to
authors and thus to the printer.

Comment: Oh my, uppercase in action! *It is official!* `♥`

Comment: Well in pdf mode pdftex can use \pdfdest, when going through dvi suitable commands has to be used - and somewhere in the middle of them there is a leavevmode. But probably only Heiko could say if it is needed. You could try `\makeatletter\begingroup\let\leavevmode\relax
\hyper@anchor{\@currentHref}\endgroup\makeatother`.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated point, but it should be relatively straightforward to use the original EPS graphics in a PDF document. However, I don't know if there are version restrictions in the workflow preventing that, or if that would make for too many changes in established procedures for authors and others.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- that's part of what's wanted; it succeeds in moving the first item up to the same line as the theorem heading.  thanks!  now, the next thing is to get rid of the wide space that precedes the item number;  that's wanted for both versions.

Comment: @MikeRenfro -- while it's true that .eps graphics can be used in a `.pdf` document, that's not relevant here, since what is also needed, and is passed on via postscript specials in the dvi file, is the scaling information, without which the line widths and font sizes can't be properly evaluated.

Comment: the space is the label width of the enumerate (numbers are right aligned in the label), you would have to change the definition of enumerate to change this.(Try with enumitem `\begin{enumerate}[align=left,leftmargin=*]`

Comment: Any reason to use dvi in XXIst century?

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov -- i tried really hard to explain why in the question.  using dvi cuts the human time for the production cycle significantly, and that in turn cuts the cost of publishing  books and journals.  human time is better spent on meaningful tasks like copyediting for comprehension and accuracy.  as soon as reasonable, cost-effective automatic means of verifying that what is in a pdf file will produce the desired result on a high-speed printing press, it will be adopted.

Answer (score 5):

you just need to put the anchor somewhere safe, here I attach it to the theorem header (which hasn't been typeset yet, it's hanging around in the box `\@labels` waiting for a paragraph to start).

I added some page breaks so that it is easier to see what happens when you click on a link.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\def\thmautorefname{Theorem}

\begin{document}


aa
\clearpage
\begin{thm}

\makeatletter
\setbox\@labels\hbox{\hyper@anchor{\@currentHref}\box\@labels}%
\makeatother
\label{thm:test}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First thing.
\item Second thing.
\item Third thing.
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\clearpage
Theorem~\ref{thm:test} and \autoref{thm:test}.

\end{document}
```